# JQuery mask v1.14.16 no longer working in Firefox 120

Tags: jquery, firefox, mask

I am using github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin v1.14.16

I have a jquery mask on one of my fields

```js
$("#socialInsNumber").mask("999-999-999");
```

It is not working with Firefox 120. It did work on previous versions. Any ideas?